How to know when to replace water filters
These are 10SL water sediment filters 10 inches long and 1 micron
In the left filter, the inside at center is not so white anymore. Does it mean the water sediment filtration no longer work? Should you replace the filters when the middle is no longer as white as new? I am thinking if it is not as white, the contaminants or rust can already reach the output side (center).


If the state of your sediment filters is causing worries and you feel that you are wasting time checking how deeply the sediment has penetrated the filter medium, you could install a differential pressure gauge that compares the pressure on the inlet and outlet of the filter while water is flowing. [Image: Pentek]

To take a scientific approach, you could do a monthly test by opening a specific faucet fully, always using the same faucet, and observing where the needle rests while water is flowing. (This assumes that your house has a pressure regulator, or that your municipal water pressure is fairly constant. If you're on a private well, always do the test when the well tank's pressure gage is at some particular pressure of your choosing.)
When the needle reaches a certain point of your choosing, you can open the filter housing and see if you agree with the gauge's assessment. If you think the filter media has some life left, reinstall and wait another month or more till the gauge reaches a higher reading.
After a little trial and error, you will learn where the needle should point to indicate that it's time to change. Mark that point with a felt-tipped pen, and from then on, no worries. You'll know exactly when it's time to change the filter based on the gauge needle.

If just for taste/sediment removval. replace water filters when the flow through them has slowed down unacceptably or when you can detect that sediment is coming through the filter.
If the sediment is a health risk you want to replace them sooner, but exactly how much sooner depends on how bad the incoming water is, and generally either you test or you take a guess and replace soon enough that you are confident you are still on the safe side.

The sediment is rust. Is rust health risk?

Generally no. Iron gets added to foods as a dietary supplement, after all.

It appears that your filter is catching ferric iron, which is insoluble. Too much ferrous iron in water could be a health risk, but the water would be undrinkable due to bad taste. If left in a glass it would turn red and leave sediment. It would turn tea and vegetables black and stain your laundry. If that's not what you have, there's no health risk from the rust in the water.

Iron gets added to food but not rust. Is it not. Also can 1 micron sediment filter remove or filter bacteria? Bec if the rust can flow to output then so can all bacteria, isnt it?

@Jtl Bacteria can get through any filter except a ceramic filter, which has extremely low flow. More of a drip than a flow. And viruses get through even ceramic filters.
